# Why does YY represent a 4 digit year in a date format for the jQueryUI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

When specifying a date format for the jQuery UI datepicker YY is a 4 digit year and Y is a 2 digit year:

YY = 2011
Y  = 11

See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Was curious why this is.

Comment: You'd probably want to ask them.

Comment: While I've offered an answer to this question I'm *also* voting to close as 'not constructive' since it solicits opinion, and without someone from the jQuery datepicker team answering the question, speculation and opinion is all we can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the single character variations (d, m, y) are the short version. Double is long version. Since the short version of a year is two digits, using `yy` specifies the long version, which is four digits. The format is not directly related to the number of digits that the date outputs.
Just as M (single) means: "Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr", and MM (double) means: "January, February, March, April". The same goes for all of the format chars.

This is unlike the standard format for PHP, which may confuse some.

The chosen format was to meet the web standards (RFC)s for date formatting.

See: [RFC-822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Comment: Which web-standards RFCs? Often I have seen "YYYY" as the long form and "YY" as the short form, although I could see an argument -- for symmetry -- against this, as per the post. Dates like [IOS8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) are actually *defined* in terms YYYY for the 4-digit year (or +-YYYYY extended).

Comment: Source: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt

Comment: In RFC822, the only thing I can find is a "Military Date" (or [Little-endian form date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date)): `DD MON YY`, where `YY` is only two digits. While still common for [web server] log files, I wouldn't consider it a modern [1982] web-standard. ISO8601, and the small common subset of it, is much less ambiguous and variants thereof are used most systems... in any case, the question is about choosing `YY/Y` instead of `YYYY/YY` to designate the format, and I can see merit with the argument for *why* it was chosen (so +1). However, I do not agree with the rest :)

Comment: Okay, unfortunately, more things use RFC822 than that ... I being slightly facetious about it not being a "current standard". In any case, RFC822 only specifies a 2-digit year and is otherwise not related to the the `YY/Y` question. In RFC822, `date = 1*2DIGIT month 2DIGIT ; e.g. 20 Jun 82`.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because they wanted to keep things such as option/variable names brief; in this usage it seems clear that `Y` indicates the short-form, whereas `YY` clearly indicates the long-form, of the date format.